# Trying to sort by date, but group matching field

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, grouping

I've been all over the different questions and answers and can't seem to find one that fits my situation.

I have a large list of data (sales orders) where we might get multiple sales orders for the same client.  I'm trying to sort the overall list by date but then group all orders for the same client together so the newer orders are brought forward with the oldest sales order for that client.  The key is we are working on clients with the oldest sales order first, so I don't simply want to sort by client and then date.  I'm not sure how to get where I need to go.  Any suggestions?

The picture in the link below shows the current and desired output.

[image: Example of current and desired output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working on a custom sort like this, I always try to create a "helper" column:

In this case I first created a reference table to rank the Clients. To do this, I copied the data to another sheet and sorted by Order Date. Then, I used Remove Duplicates (choosing only Client Name as a criteria) and finally added a new "Rank" column.

After that, I added my helper column to the original table and populated with a Vlookup. Sorted by Order Date, then by Rank, and it worked!

[image: Example]

You might choose to Record a Macro to automate most of this for future tables. Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks Donaldo.  I used a helper column with a match formula and it worked greate.  Here's what I used.
=MATCH([@[Client Name]],[Client Name],0)

Answer (score 0):

Not having the data available to play with, this is my best attempt. Select the entire table before running the sub and it will sort on column C first, then column A.

```
Sub sort()
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("C2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("A2") _
        , Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:= _
        False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End Sub
```

Obviously you could hard code the range in, or use `usedRange` or pretty much any other method to choose the range.
Hope it helps